# How can I configure the Ubuntu snap version of mosquitto?

Tags: ubuntu, mqtt, mosquitto

Ubuntu 18

Mosquitto 1.5

What's the correct way to modify the configuration file of mosquitto snap for Ubuntu?

The file in /snap/mosquitto/51/default_config.conf is read only.

ps ax shows that mosquitto is running and using

```
 6242 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh /snap/mosquitto/51/launcher.sh
 6267 ?        S      0:00 /snap/mosquitto/51/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /snap/mosquitto/51/default_config.conf
 6269 pts/1    R+     0:00 ps ax
```

Trying to change permisions does this:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-30:~$ sudo chmod +w /snap/mosquitto/51/default_config.conf
chmod: changing permissions of '/snap/mosquitto/51/default_config.conf': Read-only file system
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-30:~$
```

Any help valued!

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The details of which config file is loaded in the snap package is here:

https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/snap/launcher.sh

From this you should be able to create/edit the

```
/var/snap/mosquitto/common/mosquitto.conf
```

What is not entirely clear for me though is there's another case here too that will refer to

```
  /home/<user>/snap/mosquitto/common/mosquitto.conf
```

And it's unclear for me if `<user>` here refers to the user that the mosquitto service runs as, or the user starting the snap..

Comment: If it's run from systemd/as root, the snap uses `/var/snap/...`. If you run manually as a user, then it uses `/home/<user>/snap/...`.